# 404 Error - The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, maven, tomcat8

Really need help!
I am trying to deploy my application on to Tomcat. I tried almost every solution on stackoverflow but no luck.

```
Maven clean install [Success]
Run on server - 404 error
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 18, 2018 8:12:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext 
listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class 
org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4822)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5363)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Dependencies corresponding to Springframework security

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

[EDIT]
Tried adding scope as compile but I didn't see any change in the log.
Solutions tried:
Added Maven dependencies to Deployment Assembly
Tried with both Tomcat 8 and Tomcat 8.5
Tried adding spring-security-web to pom.xml yet not working

Comment: Can you share the pom file ? I guess your required dependencies are not there. - GrootC

Comment: Have you confirmed that these jars are being included in your war and your application's classpath?

Comment: Also, isn't that class in spring-security-web ?